# Why is it returning a warning when reshaping in R?

Tags: r, reshape

Here is my table that needs to be in wide format:

```
V1      V2        V3        V4
1       A0      numeric   string
1       A1         .         .
1       A2         .         .
1       A3         .         .
1       A4         .         .
1       A5         .         .
1       A6         .         .
1       A7         .         .
2       A0         .         .
2       A1         .         .
...     ...        .         .
```

I've been trying with something like this:

```
reshape(variable.name, timevar = "V2", idvar = "V1", direction = "wide")
```

Which has resulted in the following, which seems to be what I want:

```
V1   V3.A0     V4.A0    V3.A1     ...
1    Numeric   String   Numeric   ...
2    ...       ...      ...       ...
```

But I get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
multiple rows match for V2 = blah: first taken
```

Why is this warning happening and how can I circumvent it? I don't want to just ignore it as I'll have to do the same for several data files. Thanks! Very grateful for the help.

Comment: Assume your full dataset is in a dataframe `df` with columns `V1... V4`. Type `anyDuplicated(df[,c("V1","V2")])`. If the result is > 0, then there are duplicates somewhere, which will cause the error as @hd1 explained.

Comment: @jlhoward thanks! definitely >0, but what do I do now?

Comment: @user, to reshape as such, you need to have at most 1 entry per V1,V2 combination. So the question becomes what do *you* want to do with these multiple entries.

Answer (score 4):

As a few people have pointed out, you need to decide what you want to do with the extra value. `dcast` allows you to specify an aggregation function, and is essentially the same as `reshape` with direction wide but with the ability to specify what to do when you have multiple values.  Here is an example where basically every combination has repetitions, and we show the full vector for each as a deparsed string (e.g. 1:2 shows up as c(1, 2)).

```
library(reshape2)

# Make up data

df <- data.frame(
  V1=rep(1:3, 14), 
  V2=rep(paste0("A", 0:6), 6), 
  V3=sample(1:100, 42), 
  V4=paste0(sample(letters, 42, replace=TRUE), sample(letters, 42, replace=TRUE))  
)    
# Need to melt V3 and V4 together first because
# dcast does not allow multiple value variables,
# unfortunately, this allso coerces V1 to character

df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars=c("V1", "V2")) 

# Function to handle multiple items for one V1 - V2
# pair.  In this case we just deparse the vectors,
# but if you wanted, you could convert the numerics
# back to integers, or do whatever you want (e.g.
# paste if character, median if numeric).

my_func <- function(x) {
  paste0(deparse(x), collapse="")
}
# Now convert to wide format with dcast    

dcast(
  df.melt, 
  V1 ~ V2 + variable,
  value.var="value",
  fun.aggregate=my_func
)
```

This results in the following:

```
  V1         A0_V3         A0_V4          A1_V3         A1_V4
1  1 c("86", "93") c("yf", "pr")   c("5", "76") c("py", "aj")
2  2 c("53", "71") c("as", "mi")  c("42", "12") c("ho", "la")
3  3 c("69", "16") c("lm", "un") c("66", "100") c("xk", "px")
          A2_V3         A2_V4         A3_V3         A3_V4         A4_V3
1 c("43", "67") c("xh", "bk") c("79", "94") c("ix", "cx") c("51", "50")
2 c("14", "68") c("nq", "sr") c("25", "19") c("dw", "ay") c("28", "35")
3 c("21", "24") c("wu", "il") c("39", "88") c("vz", "yw") c("74", "65")
          A4_V4         A5_V3         A5_V4         A6_V3         A6_V4
1 c("hv", "uw") c("85", "34") c("cn", "ql") c("73", "87") c("px", "vy")
2 c("qb", "dc")  c("2", "72") c("ci", "du") c("81", "49") c("sd", "rx")
3 c("jk", "fv")  c("6", "90") c("sr", "yr") c("62", "97") c("rg", "dv")
```

The perfect solution would be a combination of `reshape` and `dcast`.  Unfortunately `dcast` (AFAIK) doesn't allow multiple Z columns, whereas `reshape` does (hence necessitating the `melt` step and the coersion to character), whereas `reshape` does not allow an aggregation function (AFAIK).

You can potentially resolve this by running `dcast` twice, once with `V3`, once with `V4`, and then merge the results, or add more intelligence in the aggregation function.

Answer (score 4):

As noted above, `reshape(...)` will generate a warning if the combinations of `idvar` and `timevar` (`V1` and `V2` in your example) are not unique. One way to guarantee uniqueness is to aggregate on these two variables. This also makes explicit @Arun's excellent point that you must decide what to do if there are duplicates. Below are several options.

```
set.seed(1)
# sample dataframe in same format as OP
type <- c("numeric","string")
df <- data.frame(V1=rep(1:10,each=8),V2=paste0("A",0:7),
                 V3=type[sample(1:2,80, replace=T)], 
                 V4=type[sample(1:2,80, replace=T)])
dupes <- df[sample(1:80,10),]   # some random duplicates
dupes[,3:4] <- type
df <- rbind(df,dupes)           # append to original df

df.wide <- reshape(df, timevar = "V2", idvar = "V1", direction = "wide")
# many warnings...

func   <- function(x) head(x,1)   # if duplicate, use first value
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), func)

func   <- function(x) tail(x,1)   # if duplicate, use last value
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), func)

# if replicated, indicate number of replications
func   <- function(x) {ifelse(length(x)==1,as.character(x), length(x))}
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), func)

# if duplicated, flag as such
func   <- function(x) {ifelse(length(x)==1,as.character(x),"duplicated")} 
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), func)

# if duplicates with different V3 or V4, indicate with "both"
func   <- function(x) {ifelse(length(unique(x))==1,as.character(x),"both")} 
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), func)

df.wide <- reshape(df.new, timevar = "V2", idvar = "V1", direction = "wide")
# no warnings - reshape succeeded.
```

There are a couple of nuances here that bear explaining. Note the use of `as.character(x)` in the functions. This is because R treats `df$V3` and `df$V4` as factors. The use of `x` would return the factor level (either 1 or 2, since these factors have only 2 levels). The use of `as.character(...)` forces R to return the factor label ("string" or "numeric").

Finally, note that you could put the function definition directly in the call to `aggregate(...)`, as in :

```
df.new <- aggregate(df[c("V3","V4")], by=list(V1=df$V1,V2=df$V2), 
                    function(x) {ifelse(length(x)==1,as.character(x),"both")})
```